# How do i enable my voice to be transmitted into remote computer on teamviewer

Tags: remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have checked all of my audio settings and teamviewer is detecting my voice and i can see the green bar moving but i can't get it to transmit into my remote controlled computer.
I would like to remote connect to a computer and then record something there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling audio in TeamViewer is done in menu
*Extras > Options > Remote control* by enabling
"Play computer sounds and music" under the section of
"Remote control defaults".

For audio to function normally in remote control sessions, the above
option needs to be enabled on *both* the participating computers.

In a meeting this is easier to do, by using the Cog icon in the
Screen Sharing card and selecting "Share computer sounds and music".